# Copying structure array elements does not work? C

Tags: c, structure, memcpy

I have a structure defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    char first_name[11];
    char last_name[21];
    char city_code[3];
    char zip_code[5];
    char area_code[4];
    char phone_num[8];
} subscriber;
```

I create an array of these structures according to input from console:

```
subscriber database[num_of_subscribers]
```

I wrote a function that should swap two of the elements in the array:

```
void swap_cells(subscriber dbase[],int index1,int index2)
{
    subscriber temp;
    memcpy(&temp,&dbase[index1],sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(&dbase[index1],&dbase[index2],sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(&dbase[index2],&temp,sizeof(temp));
}
```

And it does not work as I thought it did... any ideas why?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing to make you think it does not work?

Comment: @RSahu - The 2nd cell I am trying to copy appears corrupted.

Comment: I did not see any problem with your code with valid data and valid indices. I exercised the swapping code for a few different combinations of indices without any problem. I suspect you are overstepping bounds in setting up the data or you are using out of bound indices.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work, but simpler:

```
void swap_cells(subscriber dbase[],int index1,int index2)
{
    subscriber temp;

    temp = dbase[index1];
    dbase[index1] = dbase[index2];
    dbase[index2] = temp;
}
```

Comment: So the array of structures is actually an array of pointers to structures? According to what you wrote it seems like you are only adjusting the pointers?

Comment: @user34920 you're incorrect. This code utilizes full-structure-copying to perform the requested swap. The only "pointer" in this is `dbase` and it is dereferenced through `[]` to obtain source and target respectively.